# Django Redirect Status Code Error

Tags: django, http, redirect, testing

I'm testing a Django app. When the user logs in, I redirect him to a graphs page. To test, I write

```
response = TestCase.client.post('app/login', {credentials}, follow=True)
TestCase.assertRedirects(response, 'app/graphs')
```

which returns

```
AssertionError: False is not true : 
Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302).
```

---

Reasonable enough. [The docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) `assertRedirects` has a `status_code` parameter. Then calling

```
TestCase.assertRedirects(response, 'app/graphs', status_code=200)
```

returns

```
AssertionError: False is not true : 
Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 200).
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `status_code` parameter is the status of the redirect response. This should usually be `301` (permanent redirect) or `302` (temporary redirect).

It doesn't make sense to use `status_code=200`, because 200 is not a redirect response.

I agree that *Response code was 200 (expected 200).* looks a bit confusing, but the key part of the assertion error is *Response didn't redirect as expected*.

Since the assertion tells you that you are not being redirected, this suggests that your post to login is not working. You could try examining `response.content` to see what the problem is. Note that your urls should begin with a slash (i.e. `/app/login` and `/app/graphs`).

Comment: I'm using `window.location.href` in the client-side code to redirect and want to ensure I end up on the right page. How could I test this functionality?

Comment: You can use the Django test client to check that `response.content` contains the correct value of `window.location.href`. However, if you want to test the browser behaviour, you should be using something like Selenium. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) for more explanation.